# Get all values that share the same sibling in javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, api, loops

I'm trying to get all the **startTimes** that match the specific **dayID** from this json file being pulled from an API. So the result would be 870, 900, 930, 960, 990, 1020, 1050 from 20191106 and then the group of startTime from 20191107, etc. I'm assuming a loop of some kind, but having trouble figuring a unique identifier.

```
{
"Availability": [
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "870"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "900"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "930"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "960"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "990"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "1020"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "1050"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "360"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "390"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "420"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "360"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "390"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "420"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "450"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well, is `dayID` not a unique identifier?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .filter and .map

```
const jsonData = {
"Availability": [
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "870"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "900"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "930"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "960"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "990"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "1020"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "1050"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "360"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "390"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "420"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "360"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "390"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "420"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "450"
        }
    ]
}
const dayID = "20191106"
const startTimes = jsonData.Availability.filter(a => a.dayID === dayID).map(a => a.startTime)
console.log(startTimes)
```

Here is a Jsfiddle executing the code. https://jsfiddle.net/gho8b930/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reducer to group by dayID:

```js
const data = {
"Availability": [
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "870"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "900"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "930"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "960"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "990"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "1020"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191106",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "1050"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "360"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "390"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191107",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "420"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "360"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "390"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "420"
        },
        {
            "dayID": "20191108",
            "routeID": "313",
            "startTime": "450"
        }
    ]
}


console.log(data.Availability.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(acc[curr.dayID]){
    acc[curr.dayID].push(curr.startTime);
  } else {
    acc[curr.dayID]= [curr.startTime];
  }
  return acc;
}, {}))
```